# Warning: PDO::__construct() expects at least 1 parameter, 0 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Svetaine\functions.php on line 43

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Hello I'm new on PDO and have a problem, can somoeone help me?

```
    public function Counters()
{
    $dbh = new PDO();
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY id";
    $dbh->query($sql);
    echo '
    <div class="row2">
        <h1>Svarbios naujienos:</h1>
        <p></p>';
    $count = $c->rowCount();
    $s = 0;
    if($count > 0)
    {
        foreach ($dbh->query($sql) as $row) {
        echo '
        <p>'.$row['Naujiena'].'</p>';
    }
    }
    echo '
    </div>
    <div class="row2img">
        <img src="images/slide2.jpg" width="864" height="210">
    </div>

    ';
    return 1;
}
```

Thanks for helping
Error line $dbh->query($sql);

Comment: You should start with the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php

Comment: Did you read the manual on PDO first?

Comment: You can't just do `new PDO()`, you need to tell it what to connect to.

Comment: Do you also expect to be able to phone someone without dialling a number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this, replace your informations database.

```
public function Counters()
{
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbname", "dbuser", "dbpass");
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY id";
    $dbh->query($sql);
    echo '
    <div class="row2">
        <h1>Svarbios naujienos:</h1>
        <p></p>';
    $count = $c->rowCount();
    $s = 0;
    if($count > 0)
    {
        foreach ($dbh->query($sql) as $row) {
        echo '
        <p>'.$row['Naujiena'].'</p>';
    }
    }
    echo '
    </div>
    <div class="row2img">
        <img src="images/slide2.jpg" width="864" height="210">
    </div>

    ';
    return 1;
}
```